# How to make an transparent element overlap other elements?

Tags: css, transparency

I am trying to create an element which has the same color as the background (even if the background has multiple colors) but it still overlaps some elements.

```
#arrow_up {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   z-index: 3;
}

#arrow_up2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
   z-index: 4;
}
```

As you can see, there are two arrows. They are the same size but one of them is positioned 10px from the top and is transparent. What I want to do is to have the #arrow_up2 overlap #arrow_up with the background color. The easiest solution would be to set the #arrow_up2's color to the same color as the the background color. However, as I said, the background is dynamic and it may or may not have more than one color.

EDIT

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div id="arrow_up"></div><div id="arrow_up2"></div>
</div>
```

Additional CSS:

```
.nav {
   position: absolute;
   width: 450px;
   height: 600px;
}
```

Images:

[image: Good arrow.]

[image: Bad arrow.]

Image one shows what I want. These arrows are used in a photo gallery so there are images flowing under them. As you can see, if a red image stops under the arrow, it shows the #arrow_up2 which helps to form the shape. I know that I can simply create an arrow in photoshop but I wanted to know if it was possible in css like this.

I want the #arrow_up2 to have the same color as the background and overlap #arrow_up at the same time. There must be some transparency setting which lets you inherit the background color and overlap elements.

Comment: Post a functioning code snippet that people can tinker with

Comment: I've added some HTML and CSS and also changed the default #arrow_up color. If you set #arrow_up2's color to white, you basically achieve what I want. However, I need it to work with changing background color. (You can change the arrow's color by changing border-bottom color)

Comment: @Webster can you include a working demo or at least a screenshot of what you want and what you have because your problem looks like a bit unclear IMHO

Comment: @Webster What about `clip`? Try demo - http://jsfiddle.net/o9cqzdnt/

Comment: Added images. I don't think that clip is what I need because it only lets you clip a rectangle and I need a triangle.

Comment: _“However, as I said, the background is dynamic and it may or may not have more than one color”_ – can you show an example please how that’s supposed to look like then? (Because the one you have shown has a solid red background only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to cover element by element with transparent background - always visible is element under him. You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/o9cqzdnt/13/)

```
#arrow_up {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   border-left: 20px solid transparent;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 20px solid #ccc;
   z-index: 3;
}
#arrow_up2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 18px;
   border-left: 10px solid transparent;
   border-right: 10px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
   z-index: 4;
}
```

(let's customize sizes to make regular shapes).

Anyway, I prefer to use simple png or drawing with js [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using some javascript.

First you get background color:

```
var bg = window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
```

Then get your arrow object which color should be changed:

```
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrow_up2");
```

And just change it!

```
arrow.style.borderBottom = "20px solid " + bg;
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o9cqzdnt/68/).

Comment: Apart from the problems with reading style information like that – this won’t work for the “multiple background colors” the OP was talking about. (OP seems to rather mean that there is an image displayed behind this in any case, and not an actual background _color_.)

Comment: Ok so I misunderstood Webster's question. If it's as you're saying I think it's better to just use simple png file. I do not see any option to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As damian004 said, it's impossible. I will rather use a simple image.