# Change color on opacity overlay - CSS

Tags: css

When two opaque elements overlap, the opacities combine. Can I tell CSS to make the overlap a different color? For example, can I have two yellow elements that overlap and turn them orange in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can't via pure CSS. There is a CSS property that emulates Photoshop blending modes [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode), which isn't really supported widely yet. Although the blending mode still depends on the elements' colors and you can't specify the color for the overlapping sections.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}

.left {
  background: cyan;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  background: yellow;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Looks sweet. Can I use that to change 2 yellow elements to orange in the middle?

Comment: @Corbfon, unfortunately, no. Like I said in my answer, the overlapping section's color would depend on the elements' colors. You're basically blending two colors together so cyan + yellow = green. But yellow + yellow = yellow.

Comment: thanks for the input! Sad to hear it's not possible... have to find a hacky js way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Purely via css, I think not possible. Please try this answer,

[How to make an transparent element overlap other elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073737/how-to-make-an-transparent-element-overlap-other-elements)

https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/

You can give css at runtime via js too or you create a css class with element: first or last as second link suggested.